# perl compare array elements to single character

Tags: arrays, perl, compare

, Working on comparing all elements of an array to a single character.

```
chomp($letter=<STDIN>);

 $i=0;

 for($i=0;$i<$length:$i++){
    if(@selectword[$i]==$letter)
           {
            print("Match\n");
            }
           else
            {
            print("No Match\n");
            }
        }
 }
```

currently not working with array set as test
output is

```
match
match
match
match
```

regardless of any letter entered.

Comment: What does *"not working"* mean? The code you have posted won't even compile. You must post your *real code* and not type an example in from memory.

Comment: The compare function isn't working, it's just outputing

Answer (score 2):

As I said, the Perl that you have posted is a long way from even compiling, but it looks like you may want something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @selectword = (); # Initialise with real data

chomp (my $letter = <>);

for my $i (0 .. $#selectword) {
    if ($selectword[$i] eq $letter) {
        print("Match\n");
    }
    else {
      print("No Match\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not pasted your whole program.
but looking at the part of the code, you should be probably using string equality operator for comparing letters "eq" in line if(@selectword[$i]==$letter) instead of "==" which is for numeric comparison.